# Programming for PCI Input/Output Control

Tags: c, io, pci

My work is to develop a program which can manipulate with a pci (not express or mini) i/o . I need some references to start this. 
I'm programming in C and doing this for both Linux and Windows platform.

Comment: Most of the complexity isn't in the PCI bus itself, but the idiosyncrasies of what hangs off the other end. I don't see how a question so broad can be reasonably answered here.

Comment: anyway i have to do it )

Comment: Also, don't assume there will be enough similarity between a Unix & Linux driver to call it one and the same.

Comment: I wasn't saying you shouldn't do it, but that you seem to have about 20 different questions all rolled into one there, some of which are underspecified. It's an [entire book](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) (or two!)

Comment: waiting for more patien users )

Comment: Ask a specific question and I will (probably) give a detailed answer. Ask me to teach what could easily fill a semester in one answer and I'm less inclined to help. Calling me impatient and not reading the FAQ won't help though.

Comment: Here is a hint: read documentation. Look for the PCI specification to get started, so you know what you are dealing with. From there the respective Linux/Windows interfaces should make at least a little bit of sense. Without reading the docs you are wandering around in the dark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thing that linux machine would not allow a user space program to access pci.
You probably need to create a device driver, O'Reilly book will help here:

Any way if you ommit creating a driver there is a chapter that still could help you:
http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch09.pdf

Probably there is some device attached to the pci and you want to manipulate that device.
On linux this device should be found by the kernel and you probably can use mmap on its file in /dev/

On windows instead of mmap there is a PCIInitInfo, so if want to have the same code for both windows and linux, you will need to make some macros.